# SQL Issue with counting stock

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask one question related to SQL.

I have those tables with cars and the sales of the cars and I would like to find the stock. To do that i have to count how many values from cars VID and present on Sales VID

I tried the following query

Select Distinct count(*) From Cars , Sales  Where  Cars.VID != Sales.VID ;

And my result was 63 instead of 3 which is the desired outcome. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your requirement correctly, you want to obtain every distinct `VID` from the `Cars` table which does *not* appear in the `Sales` table (i.e. has not yet been sold).  For this case I would use `WHERE VID NOT IN ...`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VID)
FROM Cars
WHERE VID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT VID FROM Sales)
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but without a subselect. Might be faster with larger cars and sales lists and an index on VID in both tables.

SELECT COUNT(c.VID)
FROM Cars c
LEFT JOIN Sales s ON s.VID=c.VID
WHERE s.VID IS NULL

My question would be: why make a seperate sales table, if every car is unique. You could just add the sales columns to the Cars table?